# how to configure new installed visual code with already existing SHH key?

Tags: github

I have a project that I am already working and it was connected on my old pc with SSH, i got a new pc and I want to be able to push to my reposotary i already configured my git with the name and email but when i want to psuh to gitHub i am getting

```js
$ git push
The authenticity of host 'github.com (some ip)' can't be established.
ED343434 key fingerprint is SHA256: somekey.
```

how to be able to push again to github using the my old key without having to create new repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new ssh key for every device you use.
To generate the key follow this two-part guide from github:

- [Generating key and adding to ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
- [Adding key to github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Comment: so the old one is obsolete.

Comment: Not if you are still using the old pc... On github I have mutliple ssh-keys for my home-pc, my laptop and my work-pc.